# Is there a way to give a specific data always the same color in a javaFX chart?

Tags: java, css, javafx, charts, pie-chart

I am making a piechart in which you see attendances of students from a lecture.
Personally I thought it would be cool that the number of present students will always be green in the piechart. and the reasons of absence all a different shade of red. Is there any way to do this?

Here is my css:

```css
.chart {
    -fx-background-color: #484848;
}

.chart-legend {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-text-fill: #fff;
    -fx-border-color: #333;
}

.chart-legend-item {
    -fx-text-fill: #fff;
}

.default-color0.chart-pie { -fx-pie-color: green; }
.default-color1.chart-pie { -fx-pie-color: #ff0000; }
.default-color2.chart-pie { -fx-pie-color: #ce0000; }
.default-color3.chart-pie { -fx-pie-color: #a80000; }
.default-color4.chart-pie { -fx-pie-color: #870000; }
.default-color5.chart-pie { -fx-pie-color: #560000; }
.default-color6.chart-pie { -fx-pie-color: #380000; }
.default-color7.chart-pie { -fx-pie-color: #1c0000; }

.chart-pie-label-line {
    -fx-stroke: #fff;
    -fx-fill: #fff;
}

.chart-pie-label {
    -fx-fill: #fff;
}
```

And here is my Java:

```java
private void setUpPieChart() {
    this.pieChart.setLabelLineLength(8f);
    this.updatePieChart();
}

private void updatePieChart() {
    Lecture lecture = this.lectureTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

    if (lecture == null)
        this.pieChart.getData().clear();
    else
        // Get all attendances of the lecture object which was obtained from the currently selected row,
        // create a temporary dictionary by grouping all attendances by attendance type and their respective count,
        // sort the dictionary by attendance name and generate a list of pie chart slices for each dictionary item
        this.pieChart.setData(lecture.getAttendances().stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Attendance::getType,
                Collectors.counting())).entrySet().stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(item -> item.getKey()
                .toString())).map(item -> new PieChart.Data(String.format("%s: %.0f%%", item.getKey(),
                item.getValue() * 100f / lecture.getAttendaceSize()), item.getValue()))
                .collect(toCollection(FXCollections::observableArrayList)));
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I would expect your code to work, so long as you make sure the "present students" data is always first.

Answer (score 1):

Coloring of the series is done based on the order that the series is added. Right now your first series is set to be "green" so as long as you adjust your algorithm so that the first series you add to the PieChart is the "number of present students", that series will always be green.